# Building an IR system, gives error on 2nd last line i.e Name not defined

Tags: python

I'm creating an IR system which searches for the query in collection and gives result according to TF IDF ranking.
The code below is giving an error i.e: 
File "test.py", line 223, in

> document_freq = reduce(addto,DOC_Term,document_freq) NameError: name
>   'reduce' is not defined

```
import os,math,re,time,multiprocessing,itertools,argparse,sys
from collections import defaultdict
import operator
from pyparsing import *

# Term Frequency
# Wrapper for handling multi arguments
def wrap_getTF(a_b_c):
return getTF(*a_b_c)

# TF calculation for the given document. Log-normalisation is applied for TF.
# Doc -> Words
def getTF(doc,max_w_length,stopwords):
term_id=0
tf=defaultdict(float)
map_term_id=defaultdict(int)
map_id_term=defaultdict(str)

wfreq=defaultdict(int)
with open(doc,'r') as f:
for line in f:
if len(line.strip()) > 0:
list_terms=filter(lambda x: (1 < len(x) <= max_w_length) and (x not in stopwords), word_clean(re.split(r'\s+', line)))
                for w in list_terms:
                    if not w in map_term_id.keys():
                        map_term_id[w]=term_id
                        map_id_term[term_id]=w
                    wfreq[map_term_id[w]]+=1
                    term_id+=1
    for k in set(wfreq.keys()):
        # Term Frequency: 1 + log(tf)
        tf[map_id_term[k]]=1+math.log(wfreq[k],2)
    return (doc,tf)

# Word Cleaning
def word_clean(words):
    return map(lambda x: x.lower(), map(lambda x: re.sub("([^a-zA-Z]+$|^[^a-zA-Z]+)", "", x), words))

# Document Frequency
def addto(d,l):
    for (x,y) in l:
        d[y].append(x)
    return d

def get_tf_dic(pair_doc_tf):
    dic_ft=defaultdict(dict)
    for (d,tf) in pair_doc_tf:
        dic_ft[d]=tf
    return dic_ft

# Query Parsing
#Classes for Query Parsing
class Unary(object):
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.op, self.a = t[0]
class Binary(object):
    def __init__(self, t):
        self.op = t[0][1]
        self.operands = t[0][0::2]
class SearchAnd(Binary):
    def generateSetExpression(self,docFreq):
        return "(%s)" % " & ".join(oper.generateSetExpression(docFreq) for oper in self.operands)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "AND:(%s)" % (",".join(str(oper) for oper in self.operands))
class SearchOr(Binary):
    def generateSetExpression(self,docFreq):
        return "(%s)" % " | ".join(oper.generateSetExpression(docFreq) for oper in self.operands)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "OR:(%s)" % (",".join(str(oper) for oper in self.operands))
class SearchNot(Unary):
    def generateSetExpression(self,docFreq):
        return "(set(recipes) - %s)" % self.a.generateSetExpression(docFreq)   
    def __repr__(self):
        return "NOT:(%s)" % str(self.a)
class SearchTerm(object):
    def __init__(self, tokens):
        self.term = tokens[0]
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.term
    def generateSetExpression(self,docFreq):
        if self.term in docFreq:
            return "set(docFreq['%s'])" % self.term
        else:
            return "set()"

def query_parsing(path_query):
    # define the grammar
    and_=CaselessLiteral("and")
    or_=CaselessLiteral("or")
    not_=CaselessLiteral("not")
    searchTerm=Word(alphas) | quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)
    searchTerm.setParseAction(SearchTerm)
    searchExpr=operatorPrecedence(searchTerm,
                                     [
                                         (not_, 1, opAssoc.RIGHT, SearchNot),
                                         (or_, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, SearchOr),                                     
                                         (Optional(and_,default="and"), 2, opAssoc.LEFT,SearchAnd),
                                         #(and_, 2, opAssoc.LEFT, SearchAnd),
                                     ])

    test_query=list()
    try:
        with open(path_query,'rb') as f:
            for line in f:
                if len(line.strip()) > 0:
                    test_query.append(line.strip())
    except:
        print ('cannot find the query file. Use the default query:'), test_query
        pass

    return (test_query,searchExpr)

# Search, TF-IDF, and Ranking
def query(tf,docFreq,pathquery):

    # parsing the given queries
    (list_queries,searchExpr)=query_parsing(pathquery)

    # searching queries
    for t in list_queries:
        #
        # Parse the given query
        #
        print ("-----------------")
        print ("Search Query:"), t
        try:
            evalStack = (searchExpr+stringEnd).parseString(t)[0]
        except ParseException as pe:
            print ("Invalid search string"), t
            continue

        # Search Documents
        evalExpr = evalStack.generateSetExpression(docFreq)
        list_terms=evalExpr.split("'")[1::2]
        print ("Search Query Logic:"), evalExpr
        print ("Search Terms:"), list_terms

        start = time.time()
        matched_docs = eval(evalExpr)
        if not matched_docs:
             print (" (none)")
        elapsed_time=time.time()-start
        print ('Search Result: Found',len(matched_docs),'documents in', ("elapsed_time:{0}".format(elapsed_time)),'[sec]')

        print ("\nSearch Result Ranking (document name, score)")
        matched_doc_freq=defaultdict(list)
        start = time.time()

        # Document Frequency
        # Calculating Doc Freq for each query term. The intersection of the logically
        # matched docs and the pre-computed ground document frequency is computed using 'set' intersection.
        for t in set(list_terms):
            matched_doc_freq[t]=list(set(docFreq[t]).intersection(matched_docs))

        # Scoring Algorithm: Accumulate TF-IDF scores for given query terms
        scores=defaultdict(float)
        for doc in matched_docs:
            scores[doc] = reduce(lambda sum,x: sum + tf[doc][x] * math.log(1.0+1.0*(len(matched_docs))/(len(matched_doc_freq[x])+1),2),set(list_terms),0)

        # Top 10 Documents
        sorted_tfidf = sorted(scores.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
        for (doc_id,s) in sorted_tfidf[:10]:
            print (doc_id+'\t'+str(s))

        elapsed_time = time.time() - start
        print ("Searched in:{0}".format(elapsed_time)) + "[sec]"

# Main
if __name__ == "__main__":

    #(Step1) User Input
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Example: python test.py 20_newsgroups -max 15 -q query1.txt')
    parser.add_argument('path_data_file',type=str,action='store',help='Path to data file')
    parser.add_argument('-max','--word_length',nargs='?',default=15,const=15,type=int,action='store',help='Max Word Length')
    parser.add_argument('-q','--path_queries',nargs='?',default='query1.txt',const='query1.txt',type=str,action='store',help='Path to query file')

    args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    data_path=args.path_data_file
    max_word=args.word_length
    path_query=args.path_queries

    #(Step2) Read Doc Path
    files=map(lambda x: zip([x[0]]*len(x[2]),x[2]), os.walk(data_path))
    files=[y for x in files for y in x]
    path_docs=map(lambda x: [os.path.join(x[0],x[1])][0] if len(x)==2 else None,files)

    #(Step3) Term Frequency by multiprocessing
    stops=[]
    pool=multiprocessing.Pool(processes=50)
    DOC_TF=pool.map(wrap_getTF,zip(path_docs,itertools.repeat(max_word),itertools.repeat(stops)))

    #(Step4) Document Frequency
    DOC_Term=map(lambda x: zip([x[0]]*len(x[1]),x[1]),DOC_TF)
    document_freq=defaultdict(list)
    document_freq = reduce(addto,DOC_Term,document_freq)

    #(Step5) Making query and computing TF-IDF per query
    query(get_tf_dic(DOC_TF),document_freq,path_query)
```

I've used reduce but the 
Please review the code and help where I'm wrong. It says that reduce is not defined but i've used it previously in the other line as well.